# #Error- "out of memory" in jupyter notebook

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook got stuck because of infinite loop and causing an error "out of memory"

> I was working with WHILE loop in jupyter notebook, and it got stuck because of INFINTE LOOP, I can't open my (.ipynb) folder , I tried Interrupting kernel, shutdown, restart it, nothing is working, I am getting an  errorcode :out of memory, what should i do?

Comment: Can you kill the `python.exe` process in the task manager that you can get by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del? If not, probably reboot is the only option.

Comment: Tried ctrl+alt+del and reboot, i still can't access it .

Comment: Finally Resolved